# Why a function in react is getting called three times when I am calling only one time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

```js
const NewApp = (props) => {
  const [ counter, setCounter ] = useState(0)
  const incrementCounterByOne = () => setCounter(counter + 1)
  const decrementCounterByOne = () => setCounter(counter - 1)
  const setCounterToZero = () => setCounter(0)

  return (
    <div>
    <Display counter={counter} />
    <Button handleClick={incrementCounterByOne} text="Increment" />
    <Button handleClick={decrementCounterByOne} text="Decrement" />
    <Button handleClick={setCounterToZero} text="Reset" />
    {/* <button onClick={incrementCounterByOne}>Increment</button>
    <button onClick={decrementCounterByOne}>Decrement</button>
    <button onClick={setCounterToZero}>Reset</button> */}
    </div>
  )
}

const Button = (props) => {
  console.log("clicked")
  return (
    <button onClick={props.handleClick}>
    {props.text}
    </button>
  )
}
```

I am a newbie in react. When I am clicking on any button the button function is getting called three times but I am only clicking on one button at a time. I am a little confused on why so. If anyone can explain the process of how this is happening it be very helpful thank you!
[image: React rendered webpage with console log]

Comment: Wrap your funcs with curly brackets like this `const incrementCounterByOne = () => 
{ setCounter(counter + 1); }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `console.log("clicked")` runs when a Button is called:

```
const Button = (props) => {
  console.log("clicked")
```

and you have three buttons, so you see three logs whenever there's a re-render.

If you wanted to log only when a click occurs (and only log once, not three times), log inside the click handler instead.

```
<button onClick={(e) => {
  console.log('clicked');
  return props.handleClick(e);
}}>
```